# Refractive index of Gold

Tags: refraction

IOR of Gold is [0.47](https://pixelandpoly.com/ior.html).

How is it possible gold density is less than a vacuum?
After all, physically, a gold ingot is denser than air, or am I wrong?

Why index is 0.47?

I'm confused.

Comment: It is for modeling reflectivity in ray-tracing programs but would need a frequency dependence to get the color of gold.

Comment: The refractive index can be less than 1 if the phase velocity exceeds $c$, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353306/can-a-medium-can-have-refractive-index-less-than-the-reference-refractive-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The refractive index is a complex valued quantity. For a metal it is not at all proportional to density. This is only the case for a gas or at very short wavelengths. For gold it varies quite a bit in the optical range so the statement that it is 0.47 is oversimplified. Gold is a special case as its color is related to relativistic contraction of its 6s orbital, which make up its conduction band. Find the energy levels of the neutral gold atom [here](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/goldtable5.htm) and more about its metallic refractive index [here](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Au&page=Johnson).